# Emulate a UART like piece of hardware in linux

Tags: linux, embedded, simulator, socat

In order to test a piece of software, I need to write an emulator. This emulator has to represent the hardware very closely, it has to be able to start off at 300 baud, then negotiate with the software and eventually end up at another baudrate, for example. Also, things like parity and additional stop bits are very important.

How can I emulate such a device under Linux? I tried pty's, but it seems immume for baudrate settings and parity settings. I also tried socat, but it suffers the same fate: no matter how you configure the receiver, the data always arrives fine. I need this emulator to be able to send out the data on 300 baud in such a way that if you listen at 9600 baud you get rubbish at best. How can I do such a thing?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use hardware? USB-Serial adapters aren't all that complicated, and having real serial ports means that you won't have any problems due to your serial port emulation having insufficient fidelity.

Comment: Well, testing becomes a pain pretty fast if you need the actual hardware for it. If the test fails, whose fault was it? If you change some code at home instead of on location, how do you test it? Software emulation solves all of these problems, and therefore it is preferable.

Comment: Linux serial drivers do not need to talk to real hardware. 
If you consider testing under emulation worth the effort, go ahead, take an existing Linux serial driver (all the source is there and free to modify) and replace all real hardware access with sensible software responses.

Comment: @Cheiron - Yes, it's NICE to eliminate actual hardware. Right up until you realize that the emulated hardware has 'interesting' differences from real hardware.

Comment: @Cheiron - Given what you are working on, I'd suggest that you grab a pair of real USB serial adapters and plumb them together with a nul-modem cable. That lets you see what at least one set of real hardware will do. And remember that different hardware may react differently to a given 'incorrect' stimulus.